# elementary modular arithmetic problem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This problem came up in my research. I'm almost certain it's true, though I'm finding it really difficult to prove.

Suppose you have positive integers $n,m,N$ with $\gcd(n,m,N) = 1$.

Then can you find two coprime integers $b,d$ with $bm + dn \equiv 0\mod N$?

Would appreciate as short a proof of this as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply take $b=n$ and $d=-m$, and if they are not coprime, cancel their greatest common denominator.